# shell grep, regex to find a specific occurence

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

using grep I want to find all the strings like this:    `.some_char`   . 
I have a text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**,c**onsectetur adipisici elit**,s**ed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat
```

i want to find ",c" ",s" . So i need a regex. Can you help me?

***SOLUTION:***

```
cat file.txt | grep -o -E ",[a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

Comment: Does the char needs to be alphabetically? Or are spaces,... allowed as well?

Comment: `grep` print lines matching a pattern. Using grep on a line will print the line if the pattern matches it. Is this line alone? Or do you want to print parts of this line? Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: There is a flag in `grep` (`-o`) to print only the matching part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. If by some_char you mean alphabetic characters, you could do

```
grep -o ',[A-Za-z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be

```
",."
```

Furthermore you need to set some additional flag in `grep` (-o to print only the matching part)

The full command is thus:

```
grep -r ",." -o
```